# How to use one datasource for many repeaters

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba

first of all let me say I am a novice when it comes to .NET development.

I am working with an order confirmation page and lots of different services want to know essentially the same information; Order Number, Number of Items, Total Value etc...

They also want me to call javascript functions or include html tags for each product ordered.

I am currently doing this using asp:Repeaters which works fine. However they all use the same DataSource. What is frustrating is that I can't just do:

```
// in codebehind
rep_items.DataSource = CustomerOrder.Items
rep_items.DataBind()
```

and then use rep_items on all my different repeaters:

```
// .aspx page
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_items" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        _gaq.push("<%=productID%>");
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<!-- Another Service -->
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_items" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        anotherService.trackOrder("<%=productID%>");
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What I have to do is this:

```
// Code behind

rep_googleAnalytics.DataSource = CustomerOrder.Items
rep_googleAnalytics.DataBind()
rep_AnotherService.DataSource = CustomerOrder.Items // Same datasource as above
rep_AnotherService.DataBind()
// As more services are added this gets longer

// .aspx page
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_googleAnalytics" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        _gaq.push("<%=productID%>");
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<!-- Another Service -->
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_anotherService" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        anotherService.trackOrder("<%=productID%>");
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

As you can see I have to bind the same datasource to different objects. Can I use the same datasource but a different  for each service that needs the same data?

Comment: what you mean Same datasource but a different for each service? not getting exactly what you want to do

Comment: It's hard to explain but basically, Google Certified Shops wants to know about every product purchased. So does our Search software, so does our email service provider, so does Google Analytics. All these services have different APIs but they are all using the same datasource. I don't want to have to do `rep_googleAnalytics.DataSource = CustomerOrder.Items` for each service.

Comment: ok and your all service return same response I mean same name like orderNumber  ?

Comment: Essentially yes. They all want to know the same information about the products purchased. I should clarify what I mean by 'service'. These are usually 3rd party Javascript APIs.

Comment: I don't think so it's possible ya if you can create a function and assigned repeater data source from that function then it will not duplicate your code.